# Epstopdf BoundingBox not found

Tags: errors, epstopdf

Please, i need to convert some eps figures to pdf for use with pdflatex.

But, i have this warning:

```
 epstopdf curve.eps 
 ==> Warning: BoundingBox not found
```

Have you an idea please ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Sometimes this has to do with line ending differences. What does `file curve.eps` report?

Comment: i have changed set terminal wxt with set terminal postscript and it works!! Have you an explanation ?

Comment: The explanation is that the wxt terminal (assuming this is gnuplot output) does not produce an eps file and the postscript terminal does. I don't think wxt is intended to produce a file at all, but only outputs to a graphics window.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
epstool --copy --bbox curve.eps --output curve1.eps
```

This should generate proper bounding box. Then, `epstopdf curve1.eps` should work properly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning message, and the generated PDF file showed a huge empty space at the top of the figure, with the converted actual image placed at the bottom.

In my case that was caused by the presence of an empty line at the beginning of the EPS file.

My file was starting with:

```
       --> empty line
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%BoundingBox:  0 0 567 385
```

The EPS file is basically a text file. I have opened it with a text editor and deleted the empty line at the beginning: that fixed the "BoundingBox not found" warning and the conversion to PDF.

Hope that helps.