# Does epstool come with Tex Live?

Tags: texlive, epstopdf, epstool

I have an `eps` which I am trying to convert to `pdf`.
`eps2pdf` fails: "BoundingBox not found"

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136293/epstopdf-boundingbox-not-found) post recommends `epstool`.
[This](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/uncategorized/eps-file-incorrect-boundingbox/) post recommends `epstool` as well.

Matlab fails to find `epstool`.
Is this tool included with `Tex Live`?

[CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstool?lang=en) says it is part of `GSView`.

**Is `epstools` included with Tex Live**, and if not,
is there an alternative method to place a bounding box on the eps file?

[I didn't see it listed in Tex Live Manager.]

[I cannot download/install software willy-nilly at work, 
even portable software,
and I thus need a solution included with Tex Live.]

Comment: As the license is "Do Not Sell Ex­cept by Ar­range­ment" it can't be part of texlive.

Comment: Know of any alternatives included with Tex Live?

Comment: The excellent `epspdf` tex-lua script is included in TeX Live.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. Let me make sure first that we are talking about the same thing. Is this what you had in mind?

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/epstool.htm

GSview is Windows thing but on that page there is link to "UNIX download" whatever UNIX means. TeXLive package is very OS Linxu/distribution dependent. FreeBSD provides indeed separate port

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=epstool&stype=all&sektion=graphics

OpenBSD which I use doesn't provide a separate port for epstool (note that TeX Live on OpenBSD is very coarse and consists only of 4 packages three of which are really needed).

```
predrag@oko$ uname -a
OpenBSD oko.bagdala2.net 5.9 GENERIC.MP#10 amd64
predrag@oko$ man epstool
man: No entry for epstool in the manual.
```

but `man epstopdf` returns man pages so apparently that part is part of something possibly Ghostscript if not TeXLive.

I just checked two of my computing nodes running Red Hat 6.8 and Red Hat 7.2

```
man epstool
```

returns manual pages for epstool. It is the separate package on Red Hat

```
root@ari$ yum install epstool
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Package epstool-3.08-4.sdl7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Comment: I am using Windows. I'm not sure if I should run this code, or if you are verifying whether you have epstools and where it's coming from.

Comment: epstools is the part of GSView project. I trust that code about as much as you can trust any code for Windows.